# Using Shiny (r) to geocode a postcode

Tags: r, shiny, geocoding

I am trying to use Shiny to geocode a postcode.

How do I manipulate 'geocodeddata' to seperate the latitude and longitude into two seperate objects? I want to be able to use these objects to then subset a table.

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Parking Charge Notice"),
  textInput("value", label = h3("Text input"), value = "Enter text..."),
  actionButton("go", "Go"),
  actionButton("go2", "Run"),
  textOutput("text1"),
  fluidRow(
    dataTableOutput("table")
  )
    )
)
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(plyr)
library(geosphere)
library(ggmap)
library(reshape)
library(ggplot2)



shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    geocodeddata <- eventReactive(input$go,{
    geocode(input$value, output = "latlon")
  })
})
```

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: Apologies - will edit the original message. How do I manipulate 'geocodeddata' to seperate the latitude and longitude into two seperate objects? I want to be able to use these objects to then subset a table.

Comment: The result of `geocode` is a list with two named values `lat` and `lon`. So just use `geocodeddata()$lat` `geocodeddata()$lon`.